# How to disable .removeClass()

Tags: jquery, html, css, removeclass

I have a problem with `jquery-2.1.4.js`.

I have added a `layerslider` to my website, but this script changed div classes. I tried to change this script for lower versions, but it still not working.

So... 
I have classes like:

```
<a href="#" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"><p><img src="...pomoc.jpg" alt=""></p></a>
```

When I added `jQuery` script to my website, result is

```
<a href="#"><p><img src="...pomoc.jpg" alt=""></p></a>
```

This is an example, but half of website gets distorted.

Is it possible to delete a `removeClass` function from this script or add some code so It doesn't change/alter classes on DOM elements.

Comment: Removing core functionality from jQuery is not a good idea. I would check the source of the plugin and remove the offending lines, or better yet, use a different plugin that works as you require.

Comment: Is this website public-facing so that we may be able to take a look?  Or could you provide a list of plugins you are using?  It looks like bootstrap css to me for a start

Comment: you can just look for the removeClass instances and comment them

Comment: I checked other scripts in this plugin and only this jQeury script changing the html code. When I delete jquery-2.1.4.js file, everything is ok.

Comment: I don't see how adding jQuery removes classes from HTML. I think your problem originates from elsewhere, but it only showed when you added jQuery.

Comment: Yes, is public-faceing. allservicetest.iwareprint.pl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the jQuery script, modify the line that could be like this:

```
$('SELECTOR-HERE').removeClass('col-md-3 col-sm-6');
```

or

```
$('SELECTOR-HERE').removeClass('col-*');
```

or something similar.. (just search ".removeClass(" in the .js file)

---

With this:

```
$('SELECTOR-HERE').not('.escape-removeClass').removeClass('col-md-3 col-sm-6');
```

And edit your HTML as follow:

```
<a href="#" class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 escape-removeClass">
    <p>
        <img src="...pomoc.jpg" alt="">
    </p>
</a>
```

---

If you want a more accurate answer, let me see the jQuery code

Comment: I can't edit HTML code, because this is string from somewhere... This is e-commerce shop and this HTML is added from some string.

Comment: '${tags.boxesHome}'
This is string wchit show HTML code on website.

Comment: Try `$("SELECTOR-HERE").not($("PARENT-HERE SELECTOR-HERE"));`replacing SELECTOR-HERE with the selector that was already there, and PARENT-HERE with the div where you wnat that the classes are not removed.

Comment: Yep. Better. All classes is ok, but this slider has validation: 
It looks like you are using an old version (1.11.2) of the jQuery library. LayerSlider requires at least version 1.7.0 or newer.

Comment: Yep. It works. Can you help me delete validation from this slider?

Comment: It's some problem, coz JS files is packed. When I unpuck this JS,  slider doesn't work.

Comment: Here's the code
http://www.laresidenciatarifa.com/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/js/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of your code is actually using jQuery to remove the classes.

Try to find the code that is using jQuery, and comment out lines that remove classes. jQuery does not do this on its own

Comment: Nothing else script doesn't use removeClass in my website. 
allservicetest.iwareprint.pl

Comment: still.. jQuery does not automatically remove classes.

Comment: Of course there is a removeClass function in jQuery. But it doesn't call itself automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just override the standard function from jQuery, here is my jsFiddle

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/76cc9L7m/

jQuery

```
jQuery.fn.removeClass = function () {
    alert('not defined');
};

$(function () {
    $('div').removeClass('removeme');
})
```

Html

```
<div class="removeme">hello</div>
```

CSS

```
.removeme {
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

Comment: I can't edit HTML code. 
HTML is showing by string ' ${tags.boxesHome}'

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of banner:
allservicetest.iwareprint.pl

'
            .ls-layer,
            .ls-layer * {
            text-shadow: none !important;
            }

```
        .ls-s-1 {
            border-radius: 100px;
            -moz- border-radius: 100px;
            -webkit- border-radius: 100px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .plus,
        .plus2 {
            text-align: center;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px; 
            font-size: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            background: #eee;
        }

        .plus {
            color: #3b173d;
        }

        .plus2 {
            color: #1e73be;
        }

        .text,
        .text2 {
            font-size: 26px; 
        }

        .text {
            color: #eee;
        }

        .text2 {
            color: #1e73be;
        }

    </style>


        <div id="layerslider" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0px auto; ">


            <div class="ls-layer" style="slidedirection: right; transition3d: 31; ">
                <img src="http://kreaturamedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bg7a.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background">
                <h5 class="ls-s-1 plus" style=" top:310px; left: 40px; slidedirection : fade; slideoutdirection : fade; durationin : 750; durationout : 750; easingin : easeInOutElastic; rotatein : 90; rotateout : -90; scalein : .5; scaleout : .5; showuntil : 4000;"> + </h5>
                <h5 class="ls-s-1 text" style=" top:317px; left: 105px; slidedirection : fade; slideoutdirection : fade; durationout : 750; easingin : easeOutQuint; delayin : 300; scalein : .8; scaleout : .8; showuntil : 4000;"> you can add the slider elements into a centered container in full width mode </h5>
            </div>

            <div class="ls-layer" style="slidedirection: right;  transition3d: 31; ">
                <img src="http://kreaturamedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bg6a.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background">
                <h5 class="ls-s-1 plus2" style=" top:40px; left: 40px; slidedirection : fade; slideoutdirection : fade; durationin : 750; durationout : 750; easingin : easeOutQuint; easingout : easeInOutQuint; delayin : 0; delayout : 0; rotatein : 90; rotateout : -90; scalein : .5; scaleout : .5;;"> + </h5>
                <h5 class="ls-s-1 text2" style=" top:47px; left: 105px; slidedirection : fade; slideoutdirection : fade; durationout : 750; easingin : easeOutQuint; delayin : 300; scalein : .8; scaleout : .8; "> full width slider can be also responsive under a value of width </h5>
            </div>

            <div class="ls-layer" style="slidedirection: right;  transition3d: 31; ">
                <img src="http://kreaturamedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/guitars.jpg" class="ls-bg" alt="Slide background">
            </div>

        </div>'
```

```
  <script src="http://blog.web-to-print.pl/wtp/sliderwtp/jquery-easing-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://blog.web-to-print.pl/wtp/sliderwtp/jquery-transit-modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://blog.web-to-print.pl/wtp/sliderwtp/layerslider.transitions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://blog.web-to-print.pl/wtp/sliderwtp/layerslider.kreaturamedia.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
           skinsPath : 'http://blog.web-to-print.pl/wtp/sliderwtp/skins/',
           skin : 'fullwidth',
           thumbnailNavigation : 'hover',
           hoverPrevNext : false,
           responsive : true,
           responsiveUnder : 960,
           sublayerContainer : 960
        });
     });      
  </script>
```

'

Comment: This is some CODE with jQuery
http://blog.web-to-print.pl/wtp/1.jpg

This is the same code without jQUERY
http://blog.web-to-print.pl/wtp/2.jpg